# Remove all cart items on log out in stencil bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any way to remove all cart items when the user logout? I tried getting all the item **ID** and looping over it and calling the utils cart remove API on every iteration, but it seems it only remove the first one. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping over each item, I'd recommend calling the storefront cart API [delete cart endpoint](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/storefront-cart-api/cart/deleteacart).

Removing all cart items essentially deletes the cart, so the cart winds up in the same state either way. Here's a link to a [tutorial](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/cart-and-checkout/working-sf-apis#working-sf-apis_storefront-cart) on working with the storefront cart API that might help.

Comment: I don't know what happend but suddenly, this code suddents produces error. The response is 404 cart does not exist. But it works days ago and I didn't change anythin. `axios.delete("/api/storefront/carts/" + ${theCartID}).then(res => { window.location.reload(); }).catch(err => console.log(err));` Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could you confirm that the cart ID is correct? If there's anything off about the cart ID that's passed in, a 404 would be the result.